# How to remove html tags with JavaScript keep only BR, B and I tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove rich text from the div when user click the button to remove it and preserve only BR B and I tags. I have tried the function `replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")` but it removes all tags.

```
<div id="content" contenteditable></div>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    var a = $("#content").html();
    a = a.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    $("#content").html(a);
});
</script>
```

**Example input**
`<p>paragraph 1 <b>bold</b></p><br><br><p>paragraph 2 <i>italic</i></p>`

**What i want**
`paragraph 1 <b>bold</b><br><br>paragraph 2 <i>italic</i>`

Comment: do you want to remove the tags only, or also the content of those tags?

Comment: i want to remove only the tags.

Comment: Provide sample input and expected results

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: How does `<i>italic</i>` become part of output ?

Comment: Output doesn't match question

Comment: sorry, that's my mistake, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

> preserve only BR B and I tags

Try using function parameter of `.replace()` to return empty string if "b" or "br" , case insensitive, not found in match

```js
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    var a = $("#content").html();
    a = a.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, function(match) {       
      return !/br|b/i.test(match) ? "" : match
    });
    $("#content").html(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" contenteditable>
<p>paragraph 1 <b>bold</b></p><br><br><p>paragraph 2</p>
</div>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

Comment: or do the reverse and test for tags to preserve

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz "<p>" and "</p>" are matched by `RegExp` ; use callback function of `.replace()` to return empty string if matched string contains "p" character , else return matched "<b>" , "</b>" , "<br>" back to resulting string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: @charlietfl _"or do the reverse and test for tags to preserve"_ Yes, agree, would be most specific approach given description provided by OP. See updated post